# what is Best way to bind the tabular data

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to bind some tabular data in wpf  i just want to know that which control is more sufficient for this purpose Grid view ,list view or listbox

thanks in advance

shashank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListBox and ListView wo/GridView:

Best for presenting data in a non-tabular way - ie. in a long list with read-only data.

ListView w/GridView:

Great for presenting read-only data in a tabular way with no need for sorting (you have to implement sorting yourself) - has a few issues with calculating the width of the columns when you change the datasource after it was originally created.

DataGrid

Great for presenting rich editing and sorting capabilities out of the box. Simple properties will enable sorting - and you have automatic editing. Somewhat more complex though and is a a lot heavier than the other alternatives performance-wise.